# Import Excel data in ppt with python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, powerpoint

Is it possible to import Excel data, like tables, in ppt slides?

Additionally, I want to keep formatting.

I have already tried with python-pptx library, but I cannot figure how to import Excel data.
Also, when I am reading an Excel file and converting it to a data frame with pandas, it is not possible to keep any formatting (as I understood).

Comment: check out www.pptxbuilder.com

Answer (score 1):

you can use python COM library to achieve this.(You will need Office and Windows installed on the machine where you run this) here is sample VBA code that I have used on a project where I had to do this for a number of slides/tables.  The code could almost identically be used in python COM. To use python COM read  ->[the following article](http://www.s-anand.net/blog/automating-powerpoint-with-python/)

```
    For Iter = 1 To NumberofDS
        Dim MyRange As Range
        'I have sheets that are named "PER BRAND1", ""PER BRAND2" etc.. on each sheet the table is located on the same place "i.e AG8:BD20"
        Set MyRange = Sheets("PER BRAND" & Iter).Range("AG8:BD20")
        MyRange.Copy
        timestamp = DateAdd("s", 5, Now())
        
        'since I am using copy the command is external
        'so we do not know when it is completed this is
        'why I am waiting 5 seconds which should be plenty for copy to be finished.
        While Now() < timestamp
            DoEvents
        Wend
        
        PPPres.Slides("BrandperDS" & Iter).Shapes.PasteSpecial
        
        'setting the the properties of the pasted shape in powerpoint
        Set oChrShape = PPPres.Slides("BrandperDS" & Iter).Shapes(PPPres.Slides("BrandperDS" & Iter).Shapes.Count)
        With oChrShape
            .Left = 6.01 * 28.34646
            .Top = 4.44 * 28.34646
            .Height = 12.03 * 28.34646
            .Width = 26.17 * 28.34646
        End With
    Next Iter
```

Comment: I figure out how to import tables and do conditional formatting in ppt, but this was 2 years ago. Anyway, thank you for your answer. I will try with the COM library.

Comment: I didn't realize it was that long ago. Just saw it was unanswered :) Glad you made it work. Thanks for the upvote